# Instagram Api Get List of All not following back users

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get list of all user not following back using Instagram Api. 
To get all followers I'm calling Api:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

then using next_url in loop to get them all.
For checking who is not following back I use

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

which says about relationships to other users.

Problem appears when someone got more then few thousand followers, because I'm making more than limit of 5000 call/1h. Do you have any other idea how can I get list of not following back users ?

Answer (score 0):

You may get both `followed-by` and `follows` users list and compare these sets yourself.

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN